# Hide Profile2 fields depending on it's value when viewing user profile

Tags: entities, users

I am relatively new to drupal and for days I'm stuck.

I need to hide fields from the user profile page when they have a specific value. Adding a CSS class would also do it. But I prefer deleting the array element.

I try to use the `hook_profile2_view_alter()` function in my template php. Sure I can access the field options but not it's value directly.

Perhaps I'm digging in the wrong hole and there is a smooth "Drupal way" to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off putting your code in a [custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules), as you can implement [`hook_profile2_view()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.api.php/function/hook_profile2_view/7) instead. That will give you far more control over the output.

Without more specifics it's hard to be accurate but generally speaking the code would look something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_profile2_view($profile, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $field_items = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, 'field_name_of_field');
  if ($field_items) {
    $value = $field_items[0]['value'];

    if ($value == 'something') {
      $profile->content['field_name_of_field']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the super quick reply!

sadly field_get_items() throws me a *EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type profile2* back.

Comment: Sorry I just made a couple of changes to the answer (I made a mistake, you don't get the `$profile` object passed to the alter version of the hook) did you see those?

Comment: got it thank you very much. but field_get_items doesn't seem to return anything. right now I'm usually debugging with print_r. i will create a module and dig more into your solution.

*edit* ok, field_get_items is a module only function. thanks again :)